# Generate java code from existing c header and source

Tags: java, c

I have existing header (.h) and source (.c) files with some C code that i want to use in java.
I have worked with JNI, but in all those cases i had a dll and had to write a java class that would generate a header file. But in this case i have a header file allready and raw souce code.
Is there any easy way to generate java code that calls this C code ?

I have not worked with C so far so i have no clue on how to compile C code. There is a make file delivered with the C code, but i am unsure on what it will create. I ran the make file in linux enviroment and it created a file without any extension which ran a short test, but u don't know if it compiled the whole code.

Comment: You could try to use JavaCPP, which basically does everything you need (create a Java interface from the header and compile a library from the source): https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Create-New-Presets  If you need more specific info, I could add it as an answer. Let me know

Comment: Seriously, who are those complete idiots that downvote questions without giving a reason at all ?

Comment: Will take a look at JavaCPP, tied with JNA (jnaerator) allready, but somehow the resulting class in the generated jar does not contain any functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access). It's much more simple to use than JNI.

But to be able to use JNA/JNI, you need a shared library. You seem to have something that creates an executable. To run an external process, use [common-exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) or, if you know exactly what you're doing, you can try the `ProcessBuilder` API.

Comment: I looked at JNA allready, but it looks like you also need a dll to start with, and i don't have one, just the sources. Don't know how to compile the sources to a valid dll.

Comment: If the output of the C code is an executable, then you should look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/ to run it from Java. If you need to access internal structures, then you will have to learn C and how to build shared libraries. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: The compiled exe just runs a short test, but does not offer all the functions the code contains. It is some code from a tft display manufactuer to show how to control the dispaly, the compiled exe just displays a few test images on the display, but the code contains more functions that show how you can control the display. I need to call those functions in java.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to learn a bit about C and read the shared libraries tutorial I linked in the previous comment.